# Getting the current route in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

To get the current route within a non-view-model class, would the best practice be to inject the Router and use this.router.history.fragment? Or is this a no-no?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could inject the router and get the current instruction. Like this:

```
import { inject } from 'aurelia-dependency-injection'; //or framework
import { Router } from 'aurelia-router';

@inject(Router)
export class MyClass {

   constructor(router) {
      this.router = router;
   }

   getRoute() {
     return this.router.currentInstruction.config.name; //name of the route
     //return this.router.currentInstruction.config.moduleId; //moduleId of the route
   }
}
```

Comment: Please note that `currentInstruction` is still `null` in the constructor, so if you want to use it for binding, you can get it in the `created` method (see also the [component lifecycle](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/creating-components/3)

Comment: I am getting the data of the previous route here, any idea why??? Thanks.

Comment: Probably because the view hasn't changed yet. Check if you have a `canDeactivate` function

Comment: I cannot edit my own comment, but the [component lifecycle](http://aurelia.io/docs/fundamentals/components#the-component-lifecycle) link has changed.